# Access Identity Password Options after Configure Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

In the `ConfigureServices` startup method, during configuration of the Identity service, the password rules can be configured using code as follows:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
});
```

Where `options.Password` is an Identity object called `PasswordOptions`. *Please note my security is so lax merely to make working on the `Register` action a little smoother without having to deal repetitively with complex passwords.*

Now in my register page, I would like to have a `GeneratePassword` method that takes a `PasswordOptions` instance as input and generates a password conforming to those options. I would like that object to have the same values as I used setting the password options in `ConfigureServices`.

Is there any way to access these option values? So far the only solution I have is to store the password options in my `appsettings.json`, as a serialized `PasswordOptions` and use the `Options` pattern to inject a `PasswordOptions` into my `Register` page's `PageModel`. However, I may not wish to store the options in the config file, and would like to access them later just as they are hard-coded in `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just request an instance of `IOptions<IdentityOptions>` from DI in your method and then access it using something like the following:

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IdentityOptions identityOptions;

    public RegisterModel(IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
    {
        this.identityOptions = identityOptions.Value;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        identityOptions.Password.RequireDigit; // etc
    }
}
```